# develop preg replace on a html string by ignoring few spaces and styles

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am currently using `preg_replace` `PHP` function in my code to exclude some html entities. But while I am developing the code I found some difficulties in `regex` pattern which I used in my code.

I have following type of a html units,

```
<div class="css-1" style="style-1:10px; style-2: 5px"> --sample 1-- </div>
<div class="css-1" style="style-1: 10px; style-2:5px">--sample 2-- </div>
<div class="css-1" style="style-1: 10px; style-2: 5px">--sample 3--</div>
<div class="css-1" style="style-1:10px; style-2:5px"> --sample 4-- </div>
```

the structure is pretty similar, but I will get some spaces here and there.

I tried the following `regex` to exclude the html entity if I have any match from `regex`.

```
 $regex = '/(<div class="css-1" style="style-1:10px; style-2: 5px">[\s]+\-\-\b(sample 1|sample 2|sample 3|sample 4)\b\-\-[\s]+<\/div>)/';

$html = <<<EOD
<div class="css-1" style="style-1:10px; style-2: 5px"> --sample 1-- </div>
<div class="css-1" style="style-1: 10px; style-2:5px">--sample 2-- </div>
<div class="css-1" style="style-1: 10px; style-2: 5px">--sample 3--</div>
<div class="css-1" style="style-1:10px; style-2:5px"> --sample 4-- </div>
EOD;

$clean =  preg_replace($regex, '', $html);
```

But due to the bad variable spaces it doesn't work as I expected. I need to remove complete div If it contain one of sample 1,sample 2,sample 3 or sample 4. It is better if I can ignore the styles and spaces.

Eg:

```
<div>--sample 1--</div>
```

is similar to

```
<div class="css-1" style="style-1:10px; style-2: 5px"> --sample 1-- </div>
```

when it comes to `regex`.

I am not good at this `regex` and I still couldn't find how to ignore these variable spaces.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What spaces are you trying to remove? What is the result you want from the input string?

Comment: I have updated the question as it was not clear enough earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I use * to match zero or more spaces where the pattern needs it.
And  `sample [1234]{1}` will only match one of them so 14 is safe.

```
$re = '/<div\s+class=\"css\-1\"\s+style=\"style-1:\s*10px;\s+style-2:\s*5px\">.*?sample\s*[1|2|3|4]{1}--\s*<\/div>/';
$str = '<div class="css-1" style="style-1:10px; style-2: 5px"> --sample 1-- </div>
<div class="css-1" style="style-1: 10px; style-2:5px">--sample 2-- </div>
<div class="css-1" style="style-1: 10px; style-2: 5px">--sample 3--</div>
<div class="css-1" style="style-1:10px; style-2:5px"> --sample 4-- </div>
<div class="css-1" style="style-1:10px; style-2:5px"> --sample 14-- </div>';
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

https://3v4l.org/Q2m7l